# Do I score fishermen for settlements on water?

Tags: kingdom-builder

The Fisherman kingdom card states:

> 1 gold for each of your own settlements built adjacent to one or more water hexes.

With a harbor sector in play, I can move a settlement to a water hex. At the end of the game, **do I get a point for settlements *on* water hexes in addition to hexes adjacent to water?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For scoring the Fishermen card, you can ignore any settlement on a water hex, no matter if it’s adjacent to another water hex or not.

From the rules about the Fishermen card (page 5):

> Note - Extra harbor action:
>   The "Fishermen" card does not generate
>   gold for settlements on water hexes.

This is also part of BoardGameGeek’s *Kingdom Builder FAQ*: [Fishermen: no points for settlements on water hexes](http://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Kingdom_Builder_FAQ#toc23)